# Is it possible with SCSS (or SASS) add same class to several elements, but with different styles for each?

Tags: sass

This is what I want:

**From something like this (*this code doesn't work, it throws an error*):**

```
.ia-loading {
  select.& {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  input.& {
    border: 2px solid orange;
  }
}
```

**Get this:**

```
select.ia-loading { border: 2px solid blue; }
input.ia-loading { border: 2px solid orange; }
```

I have tried several combinations, none of which have worked:

*This one:*

```
.ia-loading {
  select & {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  input & {
    border: 2px solid orange;
  }
}
```

Produces this css, which is not what I want:

```
select .ia-loading { border: 2px solid blue; }
input .ia-loading { border: 2px solid orange; }
```

*This one:*

```
.ia-loading {
  select& {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  input&  {
    border: 2px solid orange;
  }
}
```

throws this error:

```
"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your problem? This code is incorrect?

Comment: Yes @Parhum, it is, console shows this error: `error styles.scss (Line 11 of _forms.scss: Invalid CSS after "  select.": expected class name, was "& {")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make small mixin for this like so:

```
@mixin test($elem) {
  #{$elem}.test {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And if you really want to use it inside your class you can use `@at-root` directive since Sass 3.3 (else you just put it outside your main class)

```
.test {
  margin: 20px;
  @at-root {
    @include test(select) {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    @include test(input) {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/ufhDi/)

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you are using '&' behind input and select?
Its only used when you want to have a specific "action" like hover, active etc.

Example

```
.ia-loading
   &:hover
      color: #FFF
```

Also in Sass you can't use brackets, that is used in scss

I also don't think you can do it the way you want it. It should be done like this:

```
.ia-loading
    border: 2px solid
select
   .ia-loading
      border-color: blue
input
   .ia-loading
      border-color: orange
```

Comment: Sorry @Sharpless512, I have never used SASS old syntax, so _SASS_ stands for _SCSS_ to me. I have edited question to explicitly mention SCSS. About the rest of your answer, 'This is not possible' would be a correct answer for me. Are you sure it is not possible? Many thanks.

Comment: If you make your code Sass, it will understand it that there is a div with the class .ia-loading and they have a child select or input. This is not what you want. The class should be 'attached' to input and select and not the otherway around. So no, for you purpose that is not possible. 

A good tool to understand sass & scss is this: http://css2sass.heroku.com/